# Page goes blank after adding to PHP foreach

Tags: php, joomla, foreach, module

Hello after I add some code to this PHP foreach the page goes blank and all I can see is a round black dot at the top left of screen.

My website is in Joomla3 and I am trying to customize a module. my site is http://get2gethersports.com

I have a recent post module that only shows the articles title.
that code is posted below

```
<?php if ($items) { ?>
<ul class="rsblog-recent-module unstyled<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx',''); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
        <li>
            <a <?php echo $opener; ?> href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsblog&view=post&id='.RSBlogHelper::sef($item->id,$item->alias).$Itemid,false); ?>">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

I would like to add an image abocve like the blog feed on http://vape-co.com

So I navigated to the component and saw the call for the image. which is posted below:

```
<div class="rsblog-entry-content">
        <?php if ($this->item->image) { ?>
        <div class="rsblog-entry-image">
            <img class="rsblog-entry-thumb img-polaroid" src="<?php echo JURI::root().'components/com_rsblog/assets/images/blog/'.$this->item->image; ?>?nocache=<?php echo uniqid(''); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>">
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

but whenever i add it or a snippet of it to the previous code it breaks....

Any ideas why it is breaking the page and how to fix it?
I tried adding in new li tags. Just adding the PHP part above the a link etc...

CODE UPDATE----

```
<?php if ($items) { ?>
<ul class="rsblog-recent-module unstyled<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx',''); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($items as $item) { var_dump($item);?>
        <li>
            <div class="rsblog-entry-content">
            <?php if ($this->item->image) { ?>
            <div class="rsblog-entry-image">
            <img class="rsblog-entry-thumb img-polaroid" src="<?php echo JURI::root().'components/com_rsblog/assets/images/blog/'.$this->item->image; ?>?nocache=<?php echo uniqid(''); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escape($this->item->title); ?>">
            </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
            <a <?php echo $opener; ?> href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsblog&view=post&id='.RSBlogHelper::sef($item->id,$item->alias).$Itemid,false); ?>">
                <?php echo $item->title; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @trzyeM- where do I put that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code. Looks like it just needed some reduction.

```
<?php if ($items) { ?>
<ul class="rsblog-recent-module unstyled<?php echo $params -> get('moduleclass_sfx',''); ?>">
<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
<li>
<?php if($item->image != '') ?>
<img src="components/com_rsblog/assets/images/blog/<?php echo $item->image;?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title. "logo";?>" width="100px"/>
<br/>
<a <?php echo $opener; ?> href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_rsblog&view=post&id='.RSBlogHelper::sef($item->id,$item->alias).$Itemid,false); ?>">
<?php echo $item->title; ?>
</a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$item->image` instead of `$this->item->image`

Comment: After `<?php foreach ($items as $item) { ?>` put `var_dump($item);` and paste here.

Comment: Its to much to write as a comment so i'm posting it to the main thing.

Comment: it wont let me post another link their so here is apic of the error [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/19l4pw.png[/IMG]